# iOS Application - intercept when a user deletes the app from device

Tags: ios, uninstallation

I'm developing an apple iOS application using Xcode.

How to know if a user removed an application from his iPhone/iPad Device?

thank you

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you have several your apps on device - you can use SHARED KEYCHAIN to detect marker you've written in deleted app. Shared keychain can be accsessed by apps sharing same **keychain access group**. Or you can get approximate statistics using some statistics framework by checking whether some application stopped logging any events for a long period of time.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. The only thing you can catch is first run of your app. There is no obvious reason for knowing when your app is uninstalled (except of spamming users). You can just keep stats to see your app usage if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

No, an app cannot detect when it is being deleted from the device.

An app runs in a sandbox / secure container. (Almost) everything outside that sandbox is just a 'mystery' for the app. Your app shouldn't need to know, so IF this is an issue at all, it is basically just a design issue for you to deal with.